# UWP app does not copy folder to AppData folder

Tags: uwp

I have a desktop app which I am converting to UWP(Universal Windows Platform) app using MSIX packaging tool. I have resources folder for my app which is getting copied to AppData/Roaming Folder on installing the msi.
But when I install the msix then my resources folder is getting copied to below path :

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\<XXXXXXXXXXXX>_2.2.1.0_x86__9r3t3jamfgx9p\**VFS\AppData**
```

The resources folder is having database files, log file & some important packages which I need to access from my c# code.

I need to access the resources folder pragmatically. How can I access this path?  Or will it get copied to some other path where I can have access

I have also checked the below path for resources folder but it is not there.

```
C:\Users\akshay.verma\**AppData\Local\Packages**\<XXXXXXX>
```

Please help me with how can I access my resources folder from c# code.

Comment: My problem is similar to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48849076/uwp-app-does-not-copy-file-to-appdata-folder
There is a line from the above link that :
The writes you performed in your code did actually work, but they did not write into the AppData\Roaming folder, but to a virtualized counterpart of this folder, which you can find in:

AppData\Local\Packages\{your app's ID}\LocalCache\Roaming\.

But the problem is I Couldn't find the resources folder here.

Comment: I answered something similar recently and may be very helpful to you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57139554/how-to-copy-a-file-from-visual-studio-project-to-uwp-applications-localfolder-o/57168891#57168891

Comment: If below answer is helpful please mark it thx.

Answer (score 0):

> C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\_2.2.1.0_x86__9r3t3jamfgx9p**VFS\AppData**

The above path is app's sandbox path, you could use Windows Storage ApI to access above path. For example:

```
var LocaFolder =  ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

If the resource file stored in the installed location (`C:\Users\akshay.verma\**AppData\Local\Packages**\<XXXXXXX>`) you could acess installation folder with the following. Then use `GetFolderAsync` method to get the sub folder.

```
StorageFolder appInstalledFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
StorageFolder Resource = await appInstalledFolder.GetFolderAsync("Resource");
var files = await Resource.GetFilesAsync();
```

After get the target file, you could call `CopyAsync` method copy the file to the destination folder. And the following shows that how to copy the folder.

```
public static async Task CopyFolderAsync(StorageFolder source, StorageFolder destinationContainer, string desiredName = null)
{
    StorageFolder destinationFolder = null;
        destinationFolder = await destinationContainer.CreateFolderAsync(
            desiredName ?? source.Name, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    foreach (var file in await source.GetFilesAsync())
    {
        await file.CopyAsync(destinationFolder, file.Name, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    }
    foreach (var folder in await source.GetFoldersAsync())
    {
        await CopyFolderAsync(folder, destinationFolder);
    }
}
```

For more info please refer [UWP file access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) .

Comment: Thanks, Now I am successfully able to copy the resource folder to local roaming folder.